# How to find the category that is both ordered & clicked by customer joining multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these below 5 tables and I am trying to find customers that ordered from the same category they clicked. With a condition where order date should be greater than the click date

Table: customers

```
email           cid         
a@gmail.com     1001            
b@gmail.com     1002            
c@gmail.com     1003
```

Table : orders

```
cid     pid     order_date      
1001    4000    Aug-1-2021      
1002    5000    Aug-1-2021      
1003    4000    Aug-1-2021
```

Table : clicks

```
cid     pid     click_date      
1001    4000    Jul-1-2021      
1002    8000    Jul-1-2021      
1003    8000    Jul-1-2021
```

Table : product

```
pid     category_id         
4000    1           
8000    2           
5000    2
```

Table : dim

```
categorty_id    category            
1               Games           
2               Books           
3               Music
```

Expected results

```
email           cid     category_clicked    category_ordered
a@gmail.com     1001    games               games
b@gmail.com     1002    books               books
```

c@gmail will be excluded because he ordered a different category than the one he clicked. I am not able to get how to fetch the data based on the category. I was only able to write a query to fetch if customers bought the same item they clicked.
Any help is appreciated. This is the query i have to find exactly what customer clicked & bought the same pid.

```
select distinct cust.email
From customers cust

Join orders o
on cust.cid=o.cid
join clicks c
on c.cid=o.cid and c.pid=o.pid

Join product prod
ON c.pid=prod.pid

inner join dim dim
on dim.category_id=prod.category_id
where o.order_date>=c.click_date
```

Comment: hm 1002 and 1003 has clicked on another category than they ordered, so b and c should be excluded

Comment: no because 1002 clicked & ordered same Books category, even though a different product.

Comment: Is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** t1: join between the customers table and the orders and product

**2.** t2: join between the customers table and the clicks and product

**3.** result join t1 to t2 with `t1.cid = t2.cid and t1.categorty_id = t2.categorty_id`

**4.** join t1 to dim

---

```
select  t1.email, t1.cid,  dim.category as category_clicked, dim.category as category_ordered 
From 
  (select cust.*,o.pid,o.order_date,prod.categorty_id
  from customers cust
  Join orders o on cust.cid=o.cid
  Join product prod on o.pid=prod.pid) t1


join (select cust.*,c.pid,c.click_date,prod.categorty_id
     from customers cust
     Join clicks c on cust.cid=c.cid
     Join product prod on c.pid=prod.pid ) t2 
on t1.cid = t2.cid and t1.categorty_id = t2.categorty_id
     
join dim on dim.categorty_id= t1.categorty_id
where t2.click_date <= t1.order_date;
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2de439f0ad99fd5b32110ea211b5b2a)

Answer (score 1):

For this, you must join 2 copies of `product`.
The 1st copy is used to fetch the category from `orders` and the 2nd to fetch the category from `clicks`, so that they can be compared:

```
SELECT c.email, c.cid, 
       d.category category_clicked,
       d.category category_ordered
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.cid = c.cid
INNER JOIN product po ON po.pid = o.pid
INNER JOIN clicks cl ON cl.cid = c.cid 
INNER JOIN product pc ON pc.pid = cl.pid
INNER JOIN dim d ON d.category_id = po.category_id AND d.category_id = pc.category_id
WHERE cl.click_date <= o.order_date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8cbe1771a816c80f75666cdafbbeda9).